# need solution in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKioI.png)

I have to ask the solution to chat up as well

i am doing project in node js my boilerplate. ejs file is in the includes folder which is in the views folder and my asset folder is also in the views folder I am very confused i want to set an icon for my web page I am facing so many errors how code should this problem anyone plese help me in this?

how to code for this?

Comment: what do you mean by `set an icon for my web page` - you mean the `/assets/logo.png`? you've done it ... yay

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.